# Fraction with components of Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I want to show how partial derivative transforms under a Lorentz transformation.
Since the partial derivative has a fixed definition with respect to the $x$-coordinate it stays unchanged: $\partial_\mu\phi(x)\rightarrow\partial_\mu\phi(\Lambda x)$. With $x^{\prime}=\Lambda x$ we get then:  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial ((\Lambda^{-1})^\mu{}_\nu\Lambda^\nu{}_\rho x^\rho)}=\frac{\partial}{\partial((\Lambda^{-1})^\mu{}_{\nu}x^{\prime\nu})}= \Lambda_\mu{}^{\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime\nu}}$$

How can one prove the following equation:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial((\Lambda^{-1})^\mu{}_{\nu}x^{\prime\nu})}= \Lambda_\mu{}^{\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime\nu}}$$

Comment: @Ghoster I actually want to use this to show a how a partial derivative transforms but I don‘t know how to proof this rigorous.

Comment: @Ghoster yes of course but that doesn‘t work properly because we would have to relabel $x$ and $x^\prime$.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this might be considered a different derivation, but I guess it goes more directly to the point. Instead of rewriting the variable you are differentiating with respect to, you can just use a chain rule. Notice that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial {x}^{\nu'}}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial {x}^{\nu'}} = \Lambda^{\nu'}{}_\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial {x}^{\nu'}}.$$

Comment: But we have $x^{\prime\nu}=\Lambda^\nu{}_\rho x^\rho$ which should give $\frac{\partial x ^{\prime\nu}}{\partial x^\mu}=\Lambda^\nu{}_\mu$.

Comment: @Silas Oops. Corrected it. The result on my answer now corresponds to Eq. (1.53) in Sean Carroll's book (Spacetime and Geometry). I used his notation with primes in the indices to make it a bit more clear.